# jQuery mobile fixed header on PhoneGap

Tags: jquery-mobile, scroll, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm writing an application on Phonegap with jQuery mobile
.
I have a fixied header and a very long list inside a listview:

```html
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="app">  
            <!-- Header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
                <h2>header</h2>
            </div>

            <!-- page conent -->
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="d">
                <ul id="list" data-role="listview">
                    <!-- the list is created dynamically -->
                </ul>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    </body>
```

The header will contain some action buttons.
I want to keep the header fixed when I scroll and I have some strange behaviors on different devices. 
How can I solve the fixed position issues?

Comment: This might help http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: I tried iScroll but it too slow for large amount of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used iscroll  see http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/ but i works just fine... if you don't like to use iscroll use fixed toolbar in jquery mobile  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html